# Unable to git add file changes

Tags: windows, git

Recently downloaded git version 2.42.0.windows.1 and I am unable to git add file changes.

When I add text to a file, git diff returns an empty result, and I am unable to stage the changes. This only works when I create or delete a file.

Comment: Edit the question with more details about the error you received, add the error message that's in the terminal or/and pictures of the IDE.

Comment: @Rodrigo The question does not mention an error message. All the OP said is that `git diff` is empty when they expect it not to be.

Comment: @Brian61354270 I meant to say that he should provide more details about what is happening, the changes that he is making in the file, the `git diff` command that he's running, the question at the moment is too vague

Comment: seeing is believing. Can you show us the commands and outputs you get in the question? (as text, _please_.... do not use screenshots... and welcome to SO!).

Comment: Can you do `git status foo.txt` updating with the file you add text into ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.